# Excluding ActionBar from MaterialContainerTransform transition

Tags: android, transition

I am developing an Android app with the new UI transitions like the MaterialContainerTransform transition.

Specifically, I am using it in fragment transactions to animate when new fragments are shown to the user.

My problem is that I do not change the action bar, but during the transition the action bar and status bar still get darker, like the rest of the old fragment, which looks weird to the user because these parts of the UI never change.

I've tried using `excludeTarget()` on the MaterialContainerTransform but unfortunately, it has no effect.

This is my current code in my destination fragment's `onCreate()`.

```
MaterialContainerTransform materialContainerTransform = new MaterialContainerTransform();

// this has no effect
materialContainerTransform.excludeTarget(R.id.toolbar, true);
materialContainerTransform.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
materialContainerTransform.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

this.setSharedElementEnterTransition(materialContainerTransform);
```

Is there any way to exclude the action and status bars so that the user does not see a weird flickering?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the scrimColor to transparent seems to stop the flickering.

```
materialContainerTransform.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

MaterialContainerTransform has a method called setDrawingViewId(@IdRes int drawingViewId)

So you want to call it as such on your MaterialContainerTransform object.

`materialContainerTransform.setDrawingViewId(R.id.view_id_here)`

Documentation for this method: "Set the id of the View whose overlay this transition will be added to.
This can be used to limit the bounds of the animation (including the background scrim) to the bounds of the provided drawing view, and also have the animation drawn at the relative z-order of the drawing view.
By default, the drawingViewId will be android.R.id.content. Additionally, if drawingViewId is the same as the end View's id, MaterialContainerTransform will add the transition's drawable to the drawingViewId's parent instead.
If the drawing view cannot be found during the initialization of the MaterialContainerTransform, then an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown."

I was looking for this solution myself.  @Barry Irvine's answer was useful, because the documentation for the setScrimColor() method references the drawingViewId, which is what the scrim color fills.  You want to apply this to a view that does not include the toolbar, and your issue will go away without getting rid of the Scrim Color concept, which obviously has a purpose, else they would not have included it.